# Print nested ng-template in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have template like following

```
<ng-template #parent>
    <ng-template #child1>
        child 1
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #child2>
        child 2
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

just want to print #child 1 and #child 2 using #parent
any idea???

Comment: Maybe using `ng-container` can help, it does not render within the DOM but you can use template directives on it: https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull i used <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet=parent"></ng-container> but not showing anything.

Comment: `ngTemplateOutlet` is relatively new and AFAIK it is not possible to pass @Inputs

Comment: What data are you passing down from parent to child?

Comment: @ undefinedMayNotBeNull i am trying to print children using @ContentChildren but showing 'templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function' error

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `<ng-content>` to project it:](https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/)

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1> Parent component </h1>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**child.component.html**

```
<h2> Child Component </h2>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Renders as:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1> Parent component </h1>
  <h2> Child component </h2>
</div>
```